# How to use a second variable from a function into other function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def dict1():
    dictt={1:[2,4,3],
          2:[3,1],
          3:[4,2,1],
          4:[1,3]}

    dicttt={1:[45,2],
            2:[12,34,343],
            3:[12,45,67,8]}

    return dictt , dicttt

def test():
    a=dict1()
    print(a[1])    

test()
```

i want to use and print dicttt inside test() function itself, 
example: I want to return 2 variables(dictt, dicttt) from one to other function and use it in other function.

Comment: What is the question?  What are you unsure of?

Answer (score 2):

What you have already will work, `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the two return values. Alternatively you can write `d1, d2 = test()`.